# The variable inside of node-horseman evaluate is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, adonis.js, node-horseman

My application has API endpoints which one of them is for deleting. The unique `data-id` is passed by parameter `/feeds/:feedID`, that accesses the Controller class, giving the param value to the Operation class' variable `feedID`. Issue: the variable `feedID` becomes `undefined` inside of `horseman` instance. Codes:

**Controller:** Executed when accessing the endpoint. It grabs the parameter value and stores in the Operation class' variable for further use

```
* destroy(request, response) {
  const googleAlertsOperation = new GoogleAlertsOperation()

  googleAlertsOperation.feedID = request.param('feedID')
  ...
```

**Operation:** With a new `feedID` value, it should proceed with its execution

```
* deleteRSSFeed() {
  var feedID = this.feedID //<-- Has the value passed from the Controller

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    horseman
      .userAgent(this.userAgent)
      .open('https://google.com/alerts')
      .evaluate(function() {
        try {
          return '#manage-alerts-div li[data-id="' + feedID + '"]' //<-- Undefined
        } catch(e) {
          reject(e)
        }
      }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      })
      .close()
  }).catch((err) => {
    this.addError(HTTPResponse.STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reject(err))

    return false
  })
}
```

I tried it without instantiating a new Promise, but same issue. Instead of passing a variable `feedID`, created at the top, passing `this.feedID` also turns `undefined`.

Comment: Is it a curse??!!!!

Comment: It is. At least I found out the issue, needed to make a new question, more specific. Apologies.

Comment: I feel you brother! Sometimes code just want to make your hair grey!

Comment: I have two other methods that work with the same way of passing data by parameters, but in this case it fails.

Comment: `this.feedID` must be undefined. Try to log it to see its value!

Comment: I did, and it's undefined only inside of `horseman`.

Comment: Figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to follow the example at the [documentation](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman#evaluation) and make it like this:

```
.evaluate(function(selector) {
  return 'li[data-id="' + selector + '"]'
}, this.feedID)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Notice the parameter `selector`. That's it.